# Using aforge videosouceplayer in wpf

Tags: wpf, aforge

I'm using aforge:videosourceplayer in wpf, what I'm in trouble is: in order to use aforge:VideoSourcePlayer in wpf, we must put it in WindowsFormsHost tag. Is there another choice if I don't want to use WindowsFormsHost?

```
<WindowsFormsHost Margin="5,5,5,201" Name="windowFormsHost" Panel.ZIndex="0">
       <aforge:VideoSourcePlayer x:Name="videoSourcePlayer" Height="200"  Margin="12,30,0,0" Width="360">
</aforge:VideoSourcePlayer>
```

Any help is appreciate, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there isn't, since WinForms elements are drawn differently from WPF Elemenets and therefore must be placed within a separate hWND(see the link below).

You didnt asked for it, but I believe you are searching for alternatives because you encountered the [**Airspace Problem**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970688%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) when using WinForms inside WPF windows.

If you are using .NET 4 or older the ZIndex property you assign in your code above will be ignored ;-), a WinForm Element within a WPF Window will be drawn allways on top of everything else (you can read more about this here: [Layout Considerations for the WindowsFormsHost Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744952%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)).

Thats why we made our own player in the end, it was very unnerving to try and layout a WinForm Element (we needed scroll funcionality and couldn't find an easy way to let the WinFormEl. disappear partially, without some ugly tweaks on the VideoSourcePlayer anyway).

If you work with .NET 4.5 you have a bit more control over the ZIndex (and other layout properties), as you can read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744952%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (it's the same Article as above but for .NET 4.5)

Note: I remember to have read a blog post where it is said that the isRedirected&CompositionMode properties (you need those to be able to layout your WinForms within WPF properly, as said in the link above) where excluded from the 4.5 release but couldnt find any official statements on this(the safest way would be to try it out :-) ).

Answer (score 1):

I was having the exact same problem; you like the Aforge Framework but don't like the WindowsFormsHost. Eventually found a solution here;

http://seaflection.wordpress.com/2012/01/29/getting-image-stream-using-webcam-in-wpf-asynchronous-ui-updating/

Sagar Mohite overcame the problem by simply creating a Compatability.dll that allows you to convert the bitmaps into the correct format so that they can be represented in Image elements rather than VideoSourcePlayers. Also required a DispatcherObject but the small amount of code that's required is all in the link + download the dll and you can start overlaying WPF controls on your Aforge Video feeds!